# Pass GET value on top of another

Tags: php, forms, variables, get

Very basic seeming PHP question here... I have a page to which I'm already passing a value, e.g.: Product.php?type=apples

Now I want a drop down form to pass another value, so i'd end up with something like: Product.php?type=apples&cost=cheap

I've tried putting these in a form that looks like:

```
<form action="./Product.php" method="POST">
<small>View:</small>
<select name="cost" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option>Choose Metrics</option>
<option value="cheap&amp;type=<?php echo $typeID?>"></option>
```

to keep the type variable and add the "cost" variable, but the ampersand gets decoded in the URL string.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks very much.

Comment: @Sudhir `method="POST"`, and you are doing it wrong, you are passing parameter as value.

Comment: Yes you are. What are you trying to accomplish? Why is `type=[typeId]` not good enough? In any case, there is always the option of doing `value="cheap:11"` and then splitting the two parts after the form is submitted in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to change  the method from `POST` to `GET`.

Secondly, a second variable, needs a second input field. You could use a hidden field for that, or let the user choose it. (Or do javascript manipulation)

Hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="cheap">
```

This can be achieved with JavaScript too ofcourse!

Comment: Thanks -- sorry, I meant to write "GET" in my example. What I'm trying to do is use Product.php?type=apples as the URL -- the "apples" variable changes a MySQL variable on the page -- then separately use the "cost" variable to display a different chunk of PHP on the page. Ideally I'd like to be able to point someone to a page with "Product.php?type=apples&value=cheap" and have it adhere to both variables (if that makes sense) -- thanks very much for your help

Comment: You are awesome -- this helped lead me in the right direction, along with Sudhir's comment below. Sorry I can't vote you up as I don't have enough "reputation" yet, but I did mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="./Product.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="your_type_value" />
<select name="cost" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option>Choose Metrics</option>
<option value="cheap"></option>
```

Comment: You are awesome. How do I vote you up? I need more "reputation"

Comment: Just an aside, I am constantly astounded by the quick responsiveness and wealth of knowledge on this board. It truly is one of the most valuable resources on the web

Comment: Yea you are rite.. there's no site as SO.